# NSDate Date returns nil 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had written date time function as this

```
-(NSString *)setDateTime:(NSDate *)pDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *strDate = [dtFormatter stringFromDate:pDate];
    [dtFormatter release];
    return strDate;
}
```

and I call function as this

```
    NSString *strDate = [self setDateTime:[NSDate date]];       
    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

But sometimes I will get strDate nil? Why this will happen,I don't know.

Am I missing some functionality needed to implement this.

If then Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say sometimes... which dates work and which don't? (it's probably a problem with your formatter)

Comment: @Alex I dont know but Did you find any problem in my code

Comment: it looks fine, just for testing try simplifying it so you don't split it off into separate methods. Also try breakpointing

Comment: Actually I had write this code in one of my app but on device sometimes it returns nil

Comment: And do not know at which time It returns nil

Comment: then try putting different date's into it yourself (rather than just passing [NSDate now])

Comment: @AlexCoplan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2187/discussion-between-mehul-and-alex-coplan)

Comment: Why don't you try [dtFormatter autorelease], instead of releasing it right away?