# Why [dateFormatter stringFormat:[NSDate date]] can not be converted to a number

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
//In NSDate category:
+ (NSString *)timeWithFormat:(NSString *)format {
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   formatter.dateFormat = format;
   return [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}

//Swift3.0 invoke method:
let nowHour: Int = Int(NSDate.time(withFormat: "HH"))!//Crash code，I can not be reproduced
```

I think when calling `[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]` the `[NSDate date]` code may be the return value is `nil`. Is this likely to happen? If so, how to reproduce it ? [NSDate date return nil question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966089/nsdate-date-returns-nil)

Device info:
  [image]

Comment: show crash  logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code I think this is a locale issue. Not all locales use 0-9 to represent time.

If I run your code over all the 740 locale identifiers that's available for me, it fails on 60 of them. A **subset** of the locale identifiers where this code fails is presented below, along with their (American) English name and the string they produce for with the format `"HH"` for 2 PM:

```
ar          Arabic              ١٤                                  
ars         Najdi Arabic        ١٤                 
as          Assamese            ১৪                                 
bn          Bengali             ১৪                                 
ckb         Central Kurdish     ١٤                                
dz          Dzongkha            ༡༤                                  
fa          Persian             ۱۴                                
hi          Hindi               १४                                 
ks          Kashmiri            ۱۴                                 
lrc         Northern Luri       ۱۴                                 
mr          Marathi             १४                                  
my          Burmese             ၁၄                                  
mzn         Mazanderani         ۱۴                                  
ne          Nepali              १४                                
pa_Arab     Punjabi (Arabic)    ۱۴                                 
ps          Pashto              ۱۴                                 
ur_IN       Urdu (India)        ۱۴                 
uz_Arab     Uzbek (Arabic)      ۱۴
```

Trying to create a number from these string like `Int("१४")!` will crash, because the Int constructor returns `nil` which is then being force unwrapped (`!`).

---

If you're interested in getting a numerical value for the hour of a given time, I would recommend that you get the hour date component using an appropriate calendar. For example:

```
Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
```

Comment: I think you are very reasonable, but the collapse of the mobile phone settings are **Chinese**, there may be other reasons?

Comment: @iCrany hard to say without knowing anything more about the crash itself.

Comment: Because it is online environment, I can only collect these data。Tomorrow I'll go deep into the query to see if there are any more useful data to collect，Thank you for your help